# character encoding mismatch on MVC and EF with mySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, character-encoding

I am new to Entity Framework and MVC usage.
I have a problem regarding character encoding.

The table I am getting results with EF4 has "`latin1_swedish_ci`" charset on mySql.
I also used Charset attribute in my connection string that my model derived from:

```
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.myModel.csdl|res://*/Models.myModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.myModel.msl;provider=Devart.Data.MySql;provider connection string=&quot;user id=user;password=pass;host=ip;database=dbname;persist security info=True; Charset=latin1
```

Eventually, what i get as a result is : GÃ¼l (expected result is: Gül )

I am a little bit lost here, any help is appreciated really.